# How to Retrieve 3 records from storages and put them into dbResult using promise join

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, promise, bluebird

How to use promise join when retrieving 3 records and put into dbResult? 
Currently, I have one record retrieve like following code,

```
 req.oracleMobile.storage.getById(registry.getIncidentPhotoStorageName(), incident_id + '_01', { sync: true }).then(
            function (result) {
                base64data = result.result;
                base64data = JSON.parse(base64data);
                dbResult.photo = base64data.image;

                res.status(result.statusCode).send(dbResult);
    },
            function (err) {
               dbResult.photo = imageData.uploadPhotoIcon;
                //ignore no photo and send db result
                res.status(200).send(dbResult);
            }
        );
```

I want to retrieve 3 records and add it like   dbResult.photo2 = base64data.image; using promise join . 
I have tried " return promise.join(retrieve1,retrieve2,retrieve3 );". it doesn't work. 
This is my code...

```
function getIncident(req, res) {
getIncidentRow(req).then(
    function (dbResult) {
        var incident_id = dbResult.id;

        const join = require('promise-join');
        return join(req.oracleMobile.storage.getById(registry.getIncidentPhotoStorageName(), incident_id + '_01',  { sync: true }).then(
            function (result) {
                base64data = result.result;
                base64data = JSON.parse(base64data);
                dbResult.photo = base64data.image;
                //res.status(result.statusCode) .send(dbResult);                                 
            },
            function (err) {
                //ignore no photo and send db result
                res.status(200).send(dbResult);
            }
        ) ,req.oracleMobile.storage.getById(registry.getIncidentPhotoStorageName(), incident_id + '_02',  { sync: true }).then(
            function (result) {
                base64data = result.result;
                base64data = JSON.parse(base64data);
                dbResult.photo2 = base64data.image;
               // res.status(result.statusCode).send(dbResult);                 
            },
            function (err) {  
                //ignore no photo and send db result
                res.status(200).send(dbResult);
            }
        ) ,req.oracleMobile.storage.getById(registry.getIncidentPhotoStorageName(),  incident_id + '_03',  { sync: true }).then(
            function (result) {
                base64data = result.result;
                base64data = JSON.parse(base64data);
                dbResult.photo3 = base64data.image;
                res.status(result.statusCode).send(dbResult);                              
            },
            function (err) {             
                //ignore no photo and send db result
                res.status(200).send(dbResult);
            }
        ), function (result) {res.status(result.statusCode).send(dbResult)}
        ); 
    }
);
```

}

Comment: "promise.join" - if that's a bluebird promise thing, perhaps add the relevant tag so bluebird people can help :p

Comment: @JaromandaX , it deosn't work when I use return promise.join (retrieve1,retrieve2,retrieve3); probably, my code structure is wrong.  :(

Comment: well, Promise.join is documented [here](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.join.html) and requires the final argument to be a *handler **function*** - not sure why a Promise library would resort to callbacks, but then, I haven't read the use case for Promise.join

Comment: @JaromandaX  I got data . But, photos come out 1 or 2, sometimes, it comes out 3 photos fully. it seems promise can't wait loading. still trying to solve that problem. :(

Comment: Can you post the code where you use .join ... and show what retrieve1 2 and 3 actually are.  Put code in the question not on a comment

Comment: @JaromandaX I have posted my code at the bottom. Thank you for help. _/\_

Comment: Your callback to .join does absolutely nothing with the results. And it's only yakking one argument. It should take 3 because you have 3 promises to join. Did you read the documentation at all

Comment: You're also res.send in two of those promises and inn the callback

Comment: Sorry, with your "Promise.join" I though you were using bluebird ... but you're using Promise-join - which has a different syntax by the look of it

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, I'm still reading  promise-join and searching example too. And I am using npm.

Comment: sorry for my misdirection regarding Promise join - your original code had `promise.join` - which suggested Bluebird - see answer below

Comment: hang on - misread documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I see you use `promise-join` and not Bluebirds `Promise.join` that makes your code almost trivial

```
const join = require('promise-join');

function getIncident(req, res) {
    getIncidentRow(req).then(dbResult => {
        var incident_id = dbResult.id;
        const getItem = suffix => req.oracleMobile.storage.getById(registry.getIncidentPhotoStorageName(), incident_id + suffix,  { sync: true })
            .then(result => {
                let base64data = result.result;
                base64data = JSON.parse(base64data);
                return base64data.image;
                // or just ... return JSON.parse(result.result).image;
            });

        return join({
            photo: getItem('_01'), 
            photo2: getItem('_02'), 
            photo3: getItem('_03')
        })
        .then(({result, errors}) => {
            Object.assign(dbResult, result);
            res.status(200).send(dbResult);
        });
    });
}
```

promise-join handles errors, therefore in `.then({result, errors}) => {` gets  two objects

```
result === {
    photo: /* resolved value of getItem('_01') */
    photo2: /* resolved value of getItem('_02') */
    photo3: /* resolved value of getItem('_03') */
}
```

and

```
errors === {
    photo: /* rejected value of getItem('_01') */
    photo2: /* rejected value of getItem('_02') */
    photo3: /* rejected value of getItem('_03') */
}
```

i.e. if `photo` resolves, there will be a `photo` property in result, but not in errors, and so on for photo2 and photo3

Now, since your original code simply ignored any photo rejections, this is perfect

```
Object.assign(dbResult, result)
```

Is all you need to assign any resolved photos to dbResult

Comment: May I know where shall I convert base64 ?

Comment: @Phyow - try now

Comment: Omg! You helped me a lot. Thank you so much for your kind help. I will help others too. Big Thanks. _/\_

Comment: If I want to return error for default image when search_item not found , where to add? Thank you.

Comment: In a catch in the getItem function

Comment: Thank you, my God, I get the result in this way. 
.then((result) => {
                let base64data = result.result;
                base64data = JSON.parse(base64data);
                return base64data.image;
               
            })
            .catch((err) =>{
                photo=imageData.uploadPhotoIcon;
                photo2=imageData.uploadPhotoIcon;
                photo3=imageData.uploadPhotoIcon;
                return (photo,photo2,photo3);
              });